# How to set a disabled default option on a select element that uses ngModel (angular 11)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I had a select element that looked like this:

```
 <select (change)="handleEvent($event)">
    <option [value]="null" selected disabled>Select thing</option>
    <ng-container *ngIf="data">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
        <option [value]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </select>
```

Note that the default option did not come from the dynamic data and I disabled it from being selected. I wanted to access the entire data object rather than just the id when an option was selected so I did this:

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (change)="handleItemSelected()">
    <option [value]="null" selected disabled>Select thing</option>
    <ng-container *ngIf="data">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
        <option [ngValue]="item">{{ item.name }}</option>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </select>
```

This worked except the disabled default option no longer showed up until I opened the select box. I did some reading and learned that this is because the default select option becomes whatever the value of

```
selectedItem
```

is when the component initializes which in this case was undefined. However, adding

```
this.selectedItem = {
  name: "Select a thing"
}
```

did not populate the field either. I tried it both on init and in the constructor. Does anyone know:

1: why the default option is not populating 
2: how to make the the default option disabled while still using ngModel

Comment: Instead of (ngModel), try (change)="handleItemSelected($event)". And in the function you can sign the value to selectedItem.

Comment: where on the event will the ngValue be then? It is not the same as the target value... @Raj

Comment: You can try console.log($event) in the function to see it's content. Most probably, you can find the ngValue in `$event.target.value`.

Comment: I had already done so and I dont see it. ngValue is an angular binding not a native js thinkg so I wouldn't expect it to be on the event.target. If you've seen it there before though I'd love to know where

Comment: replace value attribute from null to blank string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define selectedItem as null since the option has value null

```
selectedItem = null;
```

[image]